# code behaving differently in c# dll and in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

In C# I have code as follows:

```
OleDbConnection cxn = New OleDbConnection();
cxn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(csvFilePath);
cxn.Open();
cxn.Close();
```

This code executes without any error.

Same thing in powershell goes something like:

```
$cxn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$cxn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';Data Source=" + [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($csvFilePath);
$cxn.Open();
$cxn.Close();
```

But the above gives an error saying:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the machine"

I use a 64-bit Ms Windows 2008 Server R2 operating system. I've also come across another post saying if you change `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` to `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` it should work. It did work, however I don't understand why the same stuff "works" in a dll/exe, where as it fails within powershell.

However, the issue I am facing is a totally different one. Similar code is present in a web application (wcf service). I believe this runs on framework 3.5 (clr 2.0). Similar code is also present in a windows service; where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using Microsoft Jet 4.0 (only supports 32 bit) from 64 bit Powershell. Try running the same commands from the 32 bit Powershell (located at: "$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe")

The reason it works in IIS is because the application pool is set to allow execution of 32 bit  applications.